# Filter results based on From & To Date

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying below code to filter values based on From & to Date , but when i click on search button , its just refreshing page and displaying same page.
But not displaying filtered results....

[image]

**php**

```
$reg_user='';

$post_at = "";
$post_at_to_date = "";

    $queryCondition = "";
    if(!empty($_POST["search"]["post_at"])) 
{           
    $post_at = date('Y-m-d 0:0:0',strtotime($_POST["search"]["post_at"]));
    $post_at_todate = date('Y-m-d:59:59:59');
    if(!empty($_POST["search"]["post_at_to_date"])) {
        $post_at_to_date = date('Y-m-d 59:59:59',strtotime($_POST["search"]["post_at_to_date"]));
        $post_at_todate = $post_at_to_date;
    }

$queryCondition .= "WHERE post_at >= '" . $post_at . "' AND post_at <= '" . $post_at_todate . "'";

$reg_user = new USER();
$stmt = $reg_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details ".$queryCondition);
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt->execute();
```

**html**

```
<form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="">

<input type="text" placeholder="From Date" id="post_at"  
value="<?php echo $post_at; ?>" name="search[post_at]" />       
<input type="text" placeholder="To Date" id="post_at_to_date" value="<?php echo $post_at_to_date; ?>" 
name="search[post_at_to_date]" onkeyup="doFilter()" />
<input type="submit" name="search" value="search" >
```

**script**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
showOn: "button",
buttonImage: "datepicker.png",
buttonText: "Date Picker",
buttonImageOnly: true,
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'  
});
$(function() {
$("#post_at").datepicker();
$("#post_at_to_date").datepicker();
});
</script>
```

column name of date : `created_at` , table name - `order_details`. i am completely new to php , please help me.

**Edit**

when i tried `var_dump($post_at); var_dump($post_at_to_date);` , it gave result : `string(0) "" string(0) ""`

**Edit 2** i am trying below code, now var_dump is displaying results, but the values are not filtering based on selected From & To Date

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$reg_user='';

$post_at = "";
$post_at_to_date = "";
$queryCondition = "";
    if(!empty($_POST["post_at"])) 
    {           
        $post_at = date('Y-m-d 0:0:0',strtotime($_POST["post_at"]));
        $post_at_todate = date('Y-m-d:59:59:59');
        if(!empty($_POST["post_at_to_date"])) {
            $post_at_to_date = date('Y-m-d 59:59:59',strtotime($_POST["post_at_to_date"]));
            $post_at_todate = $post_at_to_date;
        }
        $queryCondition .= "WHERE post_at >= '" . $post_at . "' AND post_at <= '" . $post_at_todate . "'";
    }

    $sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM order_details $queryCondition";
    $result = $conn->query($sqlquery);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo $result->num_rows.'result found'."<br>";
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - date: " . $row["post_at"];
            echo "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results found <br>";
    }
$conn->close();
```

**form**

```
<form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="">
<input type="text" placeholder="From Date" id="post_at" value="" name="post_at" />       
<input type="text" placeholder="To Date" id="post_at_to_date" value="" name="post_at_to_date" />
<input type="submit" name="search" value="search" />
</form>
```

**script**

```
jQuery.datepicker.setDefaults({
showOn: "button",
buttonImage: "datepicker.png",
buttonText: "Date Picker",
buttonImageOnly: true,
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'  
});
$(function() {
$("#post_at").datepicker();
$("#post_at_to_date").datepicker();
});
```

**result :**

```
Array
(
    [post_at] => 
    [post_at_to_date] => 2016-11-17
    [search] => search
)
```

24result found

Notice:  Undefined index: id in `echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - date: " . $row["post_at"];`  & displaying same page.

id:  - date: 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: A time range can't be from `0:0:0` through to `59:59:59`

Comment: @Blinkydamo thanks, then what code i need to replace with that.... it was in [this tutorial](http://phppot.com/php/php-mysql-date-range-search-with-jquery-datepicker/)

Comment: No where in that piece of code does it have the time.  It is using a date field, I presume you are trying to change it to datetime.  If you want to place the time in there then use `00:00:00` and `23:59:59` otherwise change the database format to date only.

Comment: @Blinkydamo you are right,  i just changed `timestamp` to `date` in phpmyadmin , i dont need time.....

Comment: @Blinkydamo `var_dump($post_at);
var_dump($post_at_to_date);` results `string(0) "" string(0) ""` , is i need to create those 2 `columns` in table ?

Comment: And in your edited code your still using a time of 59:59:59.

Comment: okay i will make it 0:0:0 , can you please chekc code and tell me why the filtering or values is not workiing.....

Comment: Have a look at the new answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing that your date fields in your database are `date` and not `datetime` then this should work, you are currently using invalid datetimes.

```
if( !empty( $_POST[ 'post_at' ] ) ) 
{           
    $post_at        = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $_POST[ 'post_at' ] ) );
    $post_at_todate = date( 'Y-m-d' );
    if( !empty( $_POST[ 'post_at_to_date' ] ) )
    {
        $post_at_to_date = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $_POST[ 'post_at_to_date' ] ) );
        $post_at_todate = $post_at_to_date;
    }
    $queryCondition .= "WHERE DATE( created_at ) >= '" . $post_at . "' AND DATE( created_at ) <= '" . $post_at_todate . "'";
}

$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM order_details $queryCondition";
```

Some date formatting errors, have a look at the `var_dump( $sqlquery );` and make sure that the formatting is correct.  Then make sure that the result is coming through.

Comment: i am getting this : `string(85) "SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE post_at >= '2016-11-01' AND post_at <= '2016-11-01'"
0 results found ` but values are not filtering, all values are displaying after i click on `search` button......

Comment: Right in your database do you have any entries that start and finish on that date?

Comment: ok there is your issue, the dates that you have entered into your database are set to 0000:00:00 00:00:00, this is not a date that you can search for.  also you will need to add `date( post_at )` so as to look at only the date in the database.  You need to change the `post_at ` value in the database to represent an actual date.

Comment: i changed from `datetime` to `date`, please check new values here : http://prnt.sc/dac0x5

Comment: still it showing `string(101) "SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE DATE( post_at ) >= '2016-11-06' AND DATE( post_at ) <= '2016-11-06'"
0 results found `  can you please check [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/date9.php) , username : kidsdial1@gmail.com, pw : kidsdial1 , [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/date9.php)

Comment: Comment out the `$post_at` and `$post_at_todate` and replace them with these `$post_at        = '0000-00-00';
    $post_at_todate = '0000-00-00';` you still get the same result yes?

Comment: I don't think the code is the issue here, you are searching for data that is between two dates, the dates you have in your database are `0000-00-00` and your searching for `2016-11-06`, your never going to win at that.

Comment: Also delete the username and password for your site, not a great idea.

Comment: i commented those 2 lines : `$post_at = "";` & `$post_at_to_date = "";`  & tried new code : `$post_at = '0000-00-00'; 
$post_at_todate = '0000-00-00';`

Comment: i want to search dates in between from and to date of dates present in `created_at` column......

Comment: That is a change from what you have above

Comment: i am not sure whether i need `post_at` and `post_at_to_date` dates, why i need to save those dates in db ? i dont need that, all i need to to display filtered values.....

Comment: Try this - `$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM order_details where created_at >= '2016-11-17' AND created_at < = '2016-11-19'";` See what you get.

Comment: i got `string(92) "SELECT * FROM order_details where created_at >= '2016-11-17' AND created_at < = '2016-11-19'"` , `Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in` line `if ($result->num_rows > 0) {`  , `0 results found `

Comment: Sorry but you have too many things going on there and by the looks of it your running two different styles of querying.  Did you write all that code yourself?

Comment: no , its almost all are google code..... please help me this time, next time i will try to write my own code.....

Comment: Mate there is little I can do from here, it would take a long time you go through it, by the looks of it you are not getting a result back from the database, once you resolve that you need to look at getting the data from a date range, you really need to do some reading on the construction of mysqli and understand the code better.

Comment: i followed this link : http://phppot.com/php/php-mysql-date-range-search-with-jquery-datepicker/ , its working fine in link, not getting why its not working for me....

Comment: what i understood from this [link](http://phppot.com/php/php-mysql-date-range-search-with-jquery-datepicker/) is we dont need to save values in db and again no need to fetch from db, they mentioned its all about php and jquery code, is that wrong ? is i need to save in db ?

Comment: Yes you need a database, it has the connection details and the sql statement in the download file attached.  You need to maybe slow down a little and have a go at some simple tasks first and then move up to this.  You will get it in the end, just trying to jump into the deep end makes it feel like your drowning.  Good luck though, hope you get it sorted.

Comment: its not good to aks this , but is it possible to help me if i send ftp details ?

Comment: No and DO NOT SEND your ftp details to anyone, you run huge risks doing that.  I have my own work and need to do that, sorry and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try CAST:

$queryCondition .= "WHERE CAST(`post_at` as DATE) >= CAST(".$post_at." as DATE)
AND
CAST(`post_at` as DATE) <= CAST(".$post_at_todate." as DATE)  "

Comment: i got `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '". as DATE) AND CAST(post_at a' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)`

Comment: any other options ?

Comment: @abcd it's only syntax eror that you have to solve `$queryCondition .= "WHERE CAST(post_at as DATE) >= CAST(".$post_at." as DATE) AND CAST(post_at as DATE) <= CAST(".$post_at_todate." as DATE) "`

Comment: "WHERE CAST(post_at as DATE) >= CAST(".$post_at." as DATE) AND CAST(post_at as DATE) <= CAST(".$post_at_todate." as DATE) "